# JavaScript: Compressing object assignment for different cases

Tags: javascript, object, duplicates, summarization

I'm trying to set the porperties of an object based on a specific case. I think the following code can be compressed and I'm looking for the best way to go about it.

NOTE: I have considered using a switch statement but it results in pretty much the same number of lines.

```
let oNoificationData = {};
if (data.type === 'newUser') {
    oNotificationData = {
        title: `${data.user} is online!`,
        icon: `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${sHash}?d=mm`,
        body: 'A new user has come online',
    };
} else if (data.type === 'logoff') {
    oNotificationData = {
        title: `${data.user} has logged out!`,
        icon: `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${sHash}?d=mm`,
        body: 'A user has logged out'
    };
} else if (data.type === "newMsg") {
    oNotificationData = {
        title: `new message from ${data.user}`,
        icon: `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${sHash}?d=mm`,
        body: 'You have a new message!'
    };
} else if (data.type === "closeRoom") {
    oNotificationData = {
        title: `${data.user} has left the chat`,
        icon: `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${sHash}?d=mm`,
        body: 'Chat user has left'
    };
}
```

Comment: You can make an an object and reference it, in the end it is almost going to be the same amount of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So use an object

```
var notifications = {
  newUser : {
    title: `${data.user} is online!`,
    icon:`https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${sHash}?d=mm`,
    body: 'A new user has come online',
  },
  logoff : {
    title: `${data.user} has logged out!`,
    icon:`https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${sHash}?d=mm`,
    body: 'A user has logged out'
  }
}
```

and it is just

```
var obj = notifications[data.type];
```

Comment: Nice! This would result in the same amount of code correct, Is there a benefit doing it this way ?

Comment: It is less amount of code character wise and it is cleaner without all the copy and paste. You are not going to get any less lines....

Comment: @epascarello It looks like the icons are all the same. Maybe you could reduce that, just an idea.